# how to add an inline policy to allow s3:ListBucket for a certain User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to add this as an inline policy, with arn for user (principle) and arn for bucket (resource).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000:user/name"
            },
            "Action": ”s3:ListBucket”
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket name"
        }
    ]
}
```

error: Unsupported Principal: The policy type IDENTITY_POLICY does not support the Principal element. Remove the Principal element

tried adding this snippet as an inline policy but I have to find another way due to error Unsupported Principal: The policy type IDENTITY_POLICY does not support the Principal element. Remove the Principal element

Comment: Where are you going to attach the policy?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the principal element.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ”s3:ListBucket”
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: if I remove principle I get a message ''This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining"

Answer (score 0):

This should be working for you, just replace the user with correct AWS user.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1673568063233",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1673568062150",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket name",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::00000000:user/name"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

AWS policy generator is always a great place for dealing with policy generation

https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: have to make sure principle element is removed...

Comment: what is SID here?

Comment: SID is an optional field that is used as a description for the Policy statement. It can hold alphanumeric values

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you might place such a policy:

- Bucket Policy
- Policy on an IAM User

If you are creating a Bucket Policy, it will require a `Principal`.

However, if you are wanting to assign rules to a specific IAM User, then it is better to **create a policy on the IAM User themselves**. When doing this, there should *not* be a `Principal` because this is inferred by the IAM User on which the policy is placed.